# Search My Own Videos on youtube

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I want to allow the visitors of my website to search videos of my youtube account by typing keywords. So far I've been using the "key" parameter to authenticate my other requests and it worked just fine, but for this specific one I am getting a 400 code when setting the `myOwn`parameter to true.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#request

If I understand what is said in the documentation by *properly authenticated*, I'd need to get into the hassle of setting up a OAuth flow just to do that. Beside the inconvenience, this doesn't even seem to address my use case since I don't want the user of my website to be authenticated with his account but with my account : I want the `myOwn` parameter to point to my account.

How can can I achieve what I am after, with a client-side only solution  and - ideally - without OAuth ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the solution to be client-side only (e.g. a javascript front-end) your authentication credentials should be disclosed to every client and this could be dangerous because anyone could take control of your youtube account.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your interest ! Thanks I am actually aware of this, this is why I'd prefer to avoid getting into this OAuth thing and stick to api tokens. The backend is a warzone so I'd prefer to avoid touching it. I finally noticed the channelId parameter and I think it'll solve my problem

Comment: Right, your solution is the best for this problem. I thought you had to provide access also to your private videos but only through the client your are building.

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems to be to use the channelId parameter and set it to my account.